# Hibernate Many to Many in Servlet

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets

i have problem when implementing **Hibernate Many to Many** association in Web Application using Servlet.

My **POJO** Class have class type variabel in `Set`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "buku")
public class Buku {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "uid")
    private long id;

    @Column(length = 150)
    private String judul;

    @Column(name = "tgl_terbit")
    private Date tglTerbit;

    @Column(length = 150)
    private String penerbit;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bukus")
    private Set<Kategori> kategories;

    public Buku() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Buku(String judul, Date tglTerbit, String penerbit,
            Set<Kategori> kategories) {
        super();
        this.judul = judul;
        this.tglTerbit = tglTerbit;
        this.penerbit = penerbit;
        this.kategories = kategories;
    }

    // Getter and Setter
```

Here is another class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "kategori")
public class Kategori {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "uid")
    private long id;

    private String namaKategori;

    private String deskripsi;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "kategori_buku",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "kategori_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "buku_id"))
    private Set<Buku> bukus;

    // Getter and Setter
```

I have **combobox** that contains `Kategori` data.
But, in JSP file the combobox value just hold `int` value of `id_kategori`.
And i get that value in my Servlet like this :

```
...
int kategori = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id_kategori"));
...
if (idBuku.equals("") || idBuku.isEmpty()) {
        controller.save(judul, penerbit, tglTerbit, kategori);
    } else {
        // Do Update
    }
...
```

The problem is, i need to pass object as parameter in my DAO & Controller.

```
...
    // DAO
    @Override
    public void insert(Buku b) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(b);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
...
```

And here is my current Controller.

```
...
public void save(String judul, String penerbit, Date tglTerbit, int idKategori) {
        Buku b = new Buku();
        b.setJudul(judul);
        b.setPenerbit(penerbit);
        b.setTglTerbit(tglTerbit);

        // Select from kategori table 
        // I stuck in this. How i create object of kategori???

        dao.insert(b);
    }
...
```

I get stuck in my Controller.
How i can create **kategori** object just from `idKategori`? If i do select to Database first and build an object, it too slow.

Thank you. ^^

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to retrieve from the database.
First, you must make your entity `Kubu`, the owning side, and move your `mappedBy` attribute in the Kategori entity.
Then, you can instantiate a new `Kategori` instance, set only its id field, when you will insert, Hibernate will also persist in the join table.

```
...
Kategori kategori = new Kategori();
kategori.setId(idKategori);
b.setKategories(new HashSet<>());
b.getKategories().add(kategori);
...
```